# How to get dynamically inserted elements in JS (Like ADBLOCK)?

Tags: javascript

I'm inserting some dynamically tags every 1 second after page load, how could I get these elements with js. The logic would be similar to an `ADBLOCK`? for example

```
var anyTag = document.createElement('span');

setInterval(function() {
   document.body.append(anyTag);
}, 1000);

// getting the tags dynamically inserted
setInterval(function() {
//here I wanted to be able to get these elements that were added
// span, span, span...
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to select all such elements on the page initially, then do the same later and compare the differences.

```
const liveSpans = document.getElementsByTagName('span'); // live collection
let oldSpans = [...liveSpans];
setInterval(() => {
  const spansNow = [...liveSpans];
  for (const span of spansNow) {
    if (!oldSpans.includes(span)) {
      // this span was inserted
    }
  }
  oldSpans = spansNow;
}, 1000);
```

Note that if you do

```
setInterval(function() {
   document.body.append(anyTag);
}, 1000);
```

you're inserting the *same* element each iteration - if you want to insert a new element each time, create it inside the interval callback.

If you want to get the spans that were inserted *immediately* upon insertion, [attach a MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe) to a parent element (in this case, the `document.body`) with `{ childList: true }` and a callback can be attached which runs whenever elements are inserted (or removed). (Look through the [`.addedNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationRecord))

Comment: It makes sense, though, if these elements aren't just a span, but random tags. For example, several random tags are being inserted in a certain page (ADS), and I need to get these elements and remove them (el.remove()), is there something similar to your example, but get these different tags?

Comment: Do you want to keep unwanted ads from being shown? Better approach: add a CSS rule that hides them, it's much easier to manage than JavaScript. Identify a selector that will match them, then have a style tag that gives them all `display: none`. This approach has worked for me every time I visit a site often enough to be annoyed by their ads.

Comment: eg, a userscript that automatically runs on pageload: `document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('style')).textContent = '.container > span { display: none }'` where `.container > span` is replaced with a selector that matches the ads. (Or use [hosts file entries](https://github.com/StevenBlack/hosts) or an adblocker extension)

Comment: This could work if all dynamically inserted elements are not with Display block `!important`. But don't work

Comment: Are those inline styles? Hadn't thought of that, but yeah, you're right, can't overwrite those with CSS alone. But if the style is being applied with anything other than an inline style, you can override it by writing an `!important` rule with higher specificity.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're creating the elements you should have a reference to them at the time of creation. Thus, the simplest solution is to store the elements you're creating in a variable, like putting them in an Array:

```
const createdElements = [];

setInterval(function() {
   const element = document.createElement('span');
   document.body.append(element);
   createdElements.push(element);
}, 2000);

setInterval(function() {
   // getting the tags dynamically inserted
   createdElements.forEach(element => {
     console.log('I created', element);
   });
}, 1000);
```

Alternatively, just make sure the elements are *findable* by giving them something like a distinctive `className` so you can find them later.

```
setInterval(function() {
   const element = document.createElement('span');
   element.setAttribute('className', 'find-me-later');
   document.body.append(element);
}, 2000);

setInterval(function() {
   // getting the tags dynamically inserted
   document.querySelectorAll('.find-me-later');
}, 1000);
```

Comment: But I don't have a reference, the logic would be similar to an adblock anyway. Basically they are inserting random elements in a certain page, I want to get these elements and remove them, can you understand?

Comment: Well in your question you said "_I'm_ inserting some dynamically tags every 1 second after page load." It's not clear that you're looking for dynamically inserted tags inserted by something else. I'd suggest clearing up your question.

Comment: I'm trying to get all tags that were dynamically inserted after page load, in your example I just get span tag, but I would like to get any tag that is dynamically inserted after page load